# adding characters to a string

Tags: c++, string, char, line

I'm trying to get my program to recognize that the first characters in this first line need to become "Tathis". If the first character is "T" in a word, for example, Throw would become Tatrow. I'm not really sure how I could add characters...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;



int main()
{




  ifstream in;
in.open("asdf.txt");
string filevalue;

//Line 1
getline(in,filevalue);
cout <<filevalue<<endl;


//Line 2
getline(in,filevalue);
cout <<filevalue<<endl;

//Line 3
getline(in,filevalue);
cout <<filevalue<<endl;

//Line 4
getline(in,filevalue);
cout <<filevalue<<endl;

//Line 5
getline(in,filevalue);
cout <<filevalue<<endl;





return 0;
}
```

The data file is called asdf.txt and contains the following:

```
This is line1.
Hey?!
I like 17.5;
but not -2.37
Done!!
```

Comment: Write a new file?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
cout <<filevalue<<endl;
```

do

```
if (!filevalue.empty() && filevalue[0] == 'T')
    cout <<"Tat"<<filevalue.substr(1)<<endl;
else
    cout <<filevalue<<endl;
```

Comment: .empty is not allowed to be used, Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: .length? if (filevalue.length() != 0 && filevalue[0] != 'T')

Comment: .c_str()? if (filevalue.c_str()[0] != 'T')

Comment: if (filevalue != "" && filevalue[0] != 'T')

Comment: if ((filevalue + "!")[0] != 'T')

Comment: arrays are not allowed also.

Comment: @MichaelCook comments are not for code like that. And short codes must be put inside backticks `\`like this\``